# Multiplying pandas dataframe and series, element wise

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a pandas series:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({0: [1,2,3], 1: [4,5,6], 2: [7,8,9] })
y = pd.Series([-1, 1, -1])
```

I want to multiply x and y in such a way that I get z:

```
z = pd.DataFrame({0: [-1,2,-3], 1: [-4,5,-6], 2: [-7,8,-9] })
```

In other words, if element j of the series is -1, then all elements of the j-th row of x get multiplied by -1. If element k of the series is 1, then all elements of the j-th row of x get multiplied by 1.

How do I do this?

Comment: `x.apply(lambda col: col*y)`?

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly.

Comment: You can also try `(x.T * y).T`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that:

```
>>> new_x = x.mul(y, axis=0)
>>> new_x
   0  1  2
0 -1 -4 -7
1  2  5  8
2 -3 -6 -9
```

Comment: Thank You ! That is also useful for me. Just a remark we can write new_x = x.mul(y.values, axis=0) if we do not want to care about indexes

Comment: @AlexanderChervov though the final result (`new_x`), even if you use `y.values` contains the indexes - but yes this works also!

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the best answer: if the function returns a bunch of nonsensical NaNs, you should multiply by the values of the series in question like so:

```
new_x = df.mul(s.values, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Abdou points out, the answer is

```
z = x.apply(lambda col: col*y)
```

Moreover, if you instead have a DataFrame, e.g.

```
 y = pandas.DataFrame({"colname": [1,-1,-1]})
```

Then you can do

```
 z = x.apply(lambda z: z*y["colname"])
```

Comment: you should not use apply in pandas with dataframes. It is a death wish. Soooooo slow!

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply the dataframes directly.

```
x * y
```

Comment: This multiplies across rows; you want to transpose it first, multiply and then transpose again: `(x.T * y).T`.