# Multiplying Dataframes in Python (same index)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to multiply 2 dataframes (herebelow)

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

and I'm expecting something like this as a result:

[image]

I found a way to do it with numpy but I lose my index and column values.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I would just loop through all cells of dff1 and multiply them with the corresponding cell in df2. It might take some time to complete if you have a large dataframe but it does not change anything but the values in df1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplying pandas dataframe and series, element wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948935/multiplying-pandas-dataframe-and-series-element-wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply data-frame columns element wise directly:

```
for i in df1.columns:
   df1[i] *= df2['Weights']
```

It will keep index and column names of df1 and assign the good values as you wish.

Also, you can create a new data-frame (df3) the same way in order to keep the original df1 to reuse it later.

```
for i in df1.columns:
    df3[i] = df1[i]*df2['Weights']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and set the axis to "rows":

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"0": [1,2,3], "1": [2,4,6], "2": [3,6,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"weights": [.1,.2,.3]})

df1.mul(df2.weights, axis="rows")
```